# Azure Table: What result does ExcuteBatch returns?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I have a azure function app which will generate multiple entries based on one partition key. In case any error during the function execution. I first delete all entities on my azure table which have the same partition key, in case the function get retries 2nd or 3nd times and insert duplicated records.

So I decided to use ExcuteBatch operation by looping through a set of 100s entities.

I not sure what the TableBatch will return. Does it return all success deletion result?

This is what i have written at this stage.

```
var projectionQuery = new TableQuery()
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "partitionKey"))
                .Select(new[] { "RowKey" });

        var entities = table.ExecuteQuery(projectionQuery).ToList();
        var offset = 0;
        while (offset < entities.Count)
        {
            var batch = new TableBatchOperation();
            var rows = entities.Skip(offset).Take(100).ToList();
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                batch.Delete(row);
            }

            var result = table.ExecuteBatch(batch);

            offset += result.Where(x=>x.HttpStatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.NoContent).Count() + offset;
        }
```

If the above code is correct. Will there be an infinite loop where the data which tried to delete could not be deleted and it keep tried to delete.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your code will exit out of the loop as soon as any batch operation fails. Basically following line of code will throw an exception if there's a failure in deleting any of the entity in the batch.

```
var result = table.ExecuteBatch(batch);
```

One more thing I noticed in the following line of code:

```
offset += result.Where(x=>x.HttpStatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.NoContent).Count() + offset;
```

Why are you adding `offset` again towards the end of the expression when you're already doing `offset +=`?

Comment: Sorry didn't realize the plus sign in between. If I remove the offset, does that statement make sense.

Comment: If you put the `ExecuteBatch` and the next line where you change the offset in it's own `try/catch` block, then you will have a situation of infinite loop. Otherwise the code will break out of loop as soon as it fails to delete any batch. HTH.